# (BCM4345/6) WiFi works, but on the regular basis getting cfg80211_set_channel error, reason -52

Tags: wifi, embedded-linux, broadcom

I am running Linux version 6.2.14 on my board, the driver seems to be initialized properly, but once the system is booted, with an interval that is less than a minute, I get a group of (reason -52) messages:

```
[ 9.971548] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[ 10.111577] brcmfmac_wcc: brcmf_wcc_attach: executing
[ 10.117058] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Sep 4 2022 21:48:18 version 7.45.251 (16ca9cf CY) FWID 01-774406d9
...

[ 22.029564] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_escan_timeout: timer expired
[ 23.191870] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd022 fail, reason -52
[ 23.301764] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd026 fail, reason -52
[ 23.408447] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd02a fail, reason -52
[ 23.515131] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd02e fail, reason -52
[ 23.621853] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd034 fail, reason -52
[ 23.623258] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd038 fail, reason -52
[ 23.624660] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd03c fail, reason -52
[ 23.626003] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd040 fail, reason -52
[ 23.627457] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd064 fail, reason -52
[ 30.028452] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd022 fail, reason -52

...

[ 1434.084828] net_ratelimit: 10 callbacks suppressed
[ 1434.084866] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd022 fail, reason -52
[ 1434.194833] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd026 fail, reason -52
[ 1434.301570] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd02a fail, reason -52
[ 1434.408164] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd02e fail, reason -52
[ 1434.514866] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd034 fail, reason -52
[ 1434.516285] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd038 fail, reason -52
[ 1434.517679] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd03c fail, reason -52
[ 1434.519036] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd040 fail, reason -52
[ 1434.520501] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd064 fail, reason -52
[ 1434.521879] brcmfmac: cfg80211_set_channel: set chanspec 0xd068 fail, reason -52

iw reg get
global
country US: DFS-FCC
(902 - 904 @ 2), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
(904 - 920 @ 16), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
(920 - 928 @ 8), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
(2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
(5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
(5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
(5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
(5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW
(5850 - 5895 @ 40), (N/A, 27), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
(57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

phy#0
country 99: DFS-UNSET
(2402 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A)
(5140 - 5360 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A)
(5460 - 5860 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A)
```

There was a similar issue mentioned here (https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-wireless/patch/20230103124117.271988-2-arend.vanspriel@broadcom.com/#25163497) , but the fix is already in the kernel that I am using right now.

Any ideas, what could be the reason, and how to resolve it?

Tried older firmware version but that didn't help.

Thanks